# Replacing file that is an embedded resource in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have a desktop type application in development, and part of the requirements is that there are a few files that need to be part of the software, not separate files that come with the executable: user instructions, explanations, and license agreement.  Understanding this I set the files' `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.  These files are not listed in the `Resources.resx` content in the Properties section of the project or anything specific like that.

The problem I am running into is that these files have been updated.  When I replace the files via windows explorer (making sure that I'm using the same file name), I can open the file in Visual Studio and see the updated content.  However when I build the solution and run in debug and try to open the files through the links I've placed, I don't get the updated content.  I get the older content, not the new stuff.  Am I missing a step?  Or am I misunderstanding how this works, and once a file's `Build Action` is set to `Embedded Resource` that's it, and if there's new updates to the files contents that I then technically have to have a 'new' file set up as `Embedded Resource`?

Here's the code I'm using to open one of the .docx files just in case it's needed:

```c#
String destFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), _user_instructions);
        if (!File.Exists(destFileName))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using (Stream source = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("My_Project_v2.docs.User_Instructions.docx"))
            {
                using (Stream destination = File.OpenWrite(destFileName))
                {
                    source.CopyTo(destination);
                }
            }
        }
        Process P = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = { FileName = "WINWORD.EXE", Arguments = destFileName }
        };
        P.Start();
```

```c#
const String _user_instructions = "7f0cf255-74ad-4665-adb6-8d6cdd77e4d3";
```

It was suggested that I create unique guids for the embedded files.

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to "update" the files contents without essentially making a new "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Along with `BuildAction` there is `CopyToOutputDirectory` which you can set `CopyIfNewer`

Comment: @Clint so, this did put the new file in the output directory, but when accessing the content through the application it's still the old content.  It's easy for the `User Instructions` file as the old content was basically an empty word file, and the updated one has text content in it.  so in the application when i click the button to have Word open the .docx file...it opens the empty one. (which was replaced).

Comment: yea the newer file would be in your output directory, are you pointing to the right file ?

Comment: @Clint see the thing is that the Embedded file is what i'm trying to display.  The requirements were to not have a .exe AND the various files. Thus i can't just point to the "new" files that were copied to the output directory.  The "Embedded" content needs to be updated, and for whatever reason it isn't.

Comment: i've just created a brand new console app, added a text file, set it as an embedded resource and copy if newer, added some code to read the embedded resource content and write line to console, build, run, verify the content is written to console, stop debugging, change text file content, build, run, verify the new content is written to console. so, we are allegedly doing the same thing, but getting different results. perhaps if you do what i've done here with a brand new console app, you might spot differences that were missed before?

Comment: @KirkHorton can you show me the code for reading the embedded resource?  are you reading the file in the output directory or from the `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`??

Comment: @shadonar unfortunately we can't share code well in comments but yes you are correct i'm using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to read the embedded resource

Comment: @KirkHorton so this did help me understand something that was an "Ooops, I soo should have seen that a LOT earlier".  this piece right here: `if (!File.Exists(destFileName))`  basically since i've been developing this on the same machine it still had the original file in the temp directory and so instead of writing the new content would just open that old file in temp.  so i've written an else statement for those cases.